# How to use custom shell on windows 7 when connected remotely via thin client

Tags: windows, shell, remote-desktop, thin-client, windows-shell

We have a Win 7 PC that runs software within a custom shell. This shell blocks users from the operating system depending on who is logged in. When no one is logged on, the OS is inaccessible.

This works fine when working locally, but when connected through an RDP session using a HP thin client, the shell is ignored and all users have access to the operating system (ctrl+alt+del, ctrl+shft+esc...etc,).

To fix this I edited the registry to run the custom shell at logon instead of explorer.exe. This still did not work when connected from the thin client. Full access to OS for all users.

I also tried to disable some keys in the registry (windows, esc, tab). This worked on the local machine but again not when connected remotely. The key presses were still received by the OS.

This was the same using Remote desktop but also VNC.

Does anyone know of a work around for this. We are stumped and the deadline is looming!

Comment: I believe the "alternate shell" property in the RDP file is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I cretaed a Group Policy for the users and set an application to run. This replaces explorer.exe with the custom shell application and keeps users from the OS layer.

- Press windows+r and enter ‘mmc’
- File → Add/remove snap in
- Select Group Policy Object from the list on the left and press ‘Add’
- Press ‘Browse’
- Select ‘Users’ tab
- Select the user you will log into from remote machine
- Press OK
- Navigate to User Configuration→Administrative Templates→System
- Enable Custom User Interface and type in your application’s file
  path. For a custom shell type c:\Path_to_my_custom_shell\MyCustomShell.exe
- Next, go to System\CTRL+ALT+DEL Options and enable Remove Task
  Manager and all other options if required

When an RDP session is launched and the correct account is logged in to, the application will be run and the user will not be able to send ctrl+alt+del, ctrl+shft+esc or alt+tab  to the remote machine.